# change of variables in multivariate integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n, s \in \mathbb{R}$ be two variables and $\theta \in S^{n-1}$ a constant.
In the proof that I am reading, we have the following
$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{\theta^{\perp }} e^{-2 \pi i s t}f(s\theta + y) dyds & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-2 \pi i x t\theta} f(x)dx
\end{eqnarray}$ 
with $x = s\theta + y$ so  $\theta . x = s$ (because y is chosen perpendicular  to $\theta$ and norm of $\theta$ is 1) and $dx = dy ds$. My question is: how do we know that $dx = dyds$ ?

Comment: What does $\theta^\perp$ mean in the integral? Is it the integral over the plane perpendicular to $\theta$?

Comment: yes, you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider first the case where $\theta=e_n$, the versor in the direction of $x_n$. In this case, you can write $x = [x_1,\ldots,x_n]=[y_1,\ldots,y_{n-1},s]$, from which it clearly follows that $dx=dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n=dsdy_1dy_2\cdots dy_{n-1} = dsdy$. Now, if $\theta\neq e_n$, you can make an intermediate change of variables to align $\theta$ with $e_n$. If $V$ is the orthogonal matrix of that rotation, and the intermediate variable is $w$, you have $w=Vx$ (or $x=V^Tw$), so $dw = det(V)dx = dx$ (since $V$ is a rotation). Then you can apply the previous result in the new system, and get $dx = dw = dsdy$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer!